# How to send array as POST parameter/payload to webservice in Android using REST

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

Im using REST in my webservice. This is the example payload/parameter i sent when i test my webservice using `advance rest client`, with `form content type` (this is the RAW type):

```
child_id%5B%5D=1&user_id=15&group_id=1&custom=&time=17%3A17%3A00&date=&child_id%5B%5D=2
```

Where `child_id%5B%5D` in RAW means `child_id[]` in the form, so i send an `array` of `child_id` (left most and right most in above `form`). Things are fine here.

The problem occured when i tried to implement this to the Android apps, where i POST those payload/parameter using a `HashMap`. `HashMap` **cant** store two values under the same key, so i cant do something like :

```
map.put("child_id[]", 1);
map.put("child_id[]", 2);
```

The latest put will overwrite the earlier put, so the Android apps will only send `2` as value of the `child_id`.

What should i do? Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you considered using a `Collection`?

Comment: @Justin what do you mean by collection? Is it Arraylist?

Comment: What about using [JSON](http://json.org/) as a data exchange format ? [Android has built-in support for JSON parsing](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

Comment: did you try to add index to the array? i.e child_id[0] and child_id[1] so on.

Comment: @BlazeTama Yes, sorry. Technically a `HashMap` is also a `Collection`. An `ArrayList` is probably what you want.

Comment: @Muthu Thanks a lot! i followed your suggestion and its working now. Please answer my question, so i can accept it

Comment: @Justin yes i also can create something like map<string, list>, but i will stick with Muthu's answer now because its a lot easier. you can answer my question, i will upvote yours. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Could add index to the array as follows.

```
map.put("child_id[0]", 1);
map.put("child_id[1]", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the easiest way in my case

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for solving this. The easiest would be to create a class to act as a container for your parameters, and store those in an `ArrayList`

```
public class Parameter {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    // Getters, setters, other stuff.
}
```

Which you would then store in an `ArrayList`

You could also make a class to act as a parameter builder of sorts. You might do something like this:

```
public class Parameters {
    private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String key, String value) { ... }
    public ArrayList<String> getKeys() { ... }
    public ArrayList<String> getValues() { ... }
}
```

The second option requires a bit more code but adds some extra flexibility and should make for a cleaner API.

Alternatively, as you mentioned in your own comment, you have the option of using a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`. Which would also work very well in place of the `ArrayList`s in the above example.